# wd drive data is deleting but not opening

Tags: 20.04, mount, hard-drive, data-recovery, ddrescue

I have a drive "wd my passport" 1tb. I am connecting it on Ubuntu 20LTS.

I  am not able to open any data, not even able to copy or move any data. While Coying ubuntu gives error of I/O.

But I am able to delete few files and folder which is not necessary.

Why is so?

I even tried ddrescue to recover ,but it's very slow, too slow.I lost my patience and got recovered 1gb of data through ddrescue and then deleted the .img file also.

I even tried a powershell script in windows 10 , script was developed by davor josipovic.But copying ecah file separately is hard job and time taking.

I  just want to know why deleting files is easy and accessing files hard? What can be the solution to get files fastest and easiest way possible.

Comment: how are you mounting the share? If through fstab, please [edit] your question and post the fstab line in use.

Comment: Please show us the `mount` line for the My Passport. Run `mount` and pick out the My Passport. Please edit your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]